# jQuery: Click select Previous / Closest div with selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this, parent, closest

I’ve being sitting for some while trying to solve a issue which I’m certain is quite simple but it just can’t get it to work.

I got this HTML:

```
<div class="span4">
    <div id="content" class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="add">
    <div class="dropdown btn-group">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            Add element
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="addToColumn" data-col="1">
            <li><a href="#" id="headline">Headline</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="file">File</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="linebreak">Linebreak</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is wrapped inside a div (class=row) which is again wrapped inside another div (class=container).

Now, when I press either of the three links (Headline, File or Linebreak) I have some JS to do some ajax and then insert some content in the empty div **content**.

But for the life of me I just can’t select the div.

I should mention, that the block of code is repeated three times, so I have three columns which each contain same dropdown menu with same three links and I want to make it as flexible as possible (before I used some different data-? attributes, but I want to use as few of those if possible).

My JS code looks something like this right now:

```
$("#addToColumn li a").click(function() {
    var elementType = $(this).attr('id');

// I’ve tried this but with no luck:
var col = $(this).closest("div#content");
    // AND
    var col = $(this).prev("div#content");
}
```

There are something which confuses me with this DOM tree. I want want each of the dropdown menus to insert something in the right wrapper-div for the right column and I want to try to do it without the use of some numeric “ID’s” but just select the “closest” **content** div and insert the data in this.

How do I go about doing that?

Any help if very appreciated

-Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have 1 element having `id="content"`. having more than one is invalid and can cause unexpected behaviour. the rest of the code seems about right. if you change your `id` to `class` the following should work: `var col = $(this).parents(".row").find(".content");`. Same goes for `id="addToColumn"`, `id` is meant to be unique - use classes instead.

Comment: Unless OP only have one div with the id "content". Then (s)he can simple use `jQuery('#content')` or `jQuery(document.getElementById('content'))`

Comment: He explicitly stated that "the block of code is repeated three times" + the code is otherwise correct.

Comment: `var col = $(this).closest("div.content");` is wrong. `content` is not a parent of `$(this)` but yes i agree `id`'s need to be unique.

Comment: Thanks guys! I used your code Yotam Omer and a bit of name-changing but otherwise precisely the same. Instead of using (".row") I changed it to (".span4"). You are of cause absolutely right about the ID's - I don't know what I was thinking but it should be clear for next time I'm struggling with same kind of problem. Thanks again, you just saved my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try

```
var col = $(this).closest("div.add").prev();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `#content` is not a parent of the `a` and `.prev()` is only for siblings, you need to get the closest parent who is the sibling of `#content` like that :

```
$(this).closest(".add").prev();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the parents() function from jquery and then traverse back down. Although Yotam is more correct, id's should be unique.

Like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WHSpU/

```
$(this).parents(".row").find("#content").first().append('some stuff');
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
   <div class="span4">
      <div class="content"></div>
      <div class="add">
        <div class="dropdown btn-group">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Add element
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu addToColumn" data-col="1">
                <li><a href="#" class="headline">Headline</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="file">File</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="linebreak">Linebreak</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
      <div class="content"></div>
      <div class="add">
        <div class="dropdown btn-group">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Add element
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu addToColumn" data-col="2">
                <li><a href="#" class="headline">Headline</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="file">File</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="linebreak">Linebreak</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
      <div class="content"></div>
      <div class="add">
        <div class="dropdown btn-group">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Add element
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu addToColumn" data-col="3">
                <li><a href="#" class="headline">Headline</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="file">File</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="linebreak">Linebreak</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(".addToColumn li a").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myContentDiv = $(this).closest('.content');
        myContentDiv.load(myData);
    }
```